# Symbol "." in the derive of Quanto Adjustment

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am reading "Analysis, Geometry and Modeling in Finance". In section 2.10.2 which derives the quanto adjustment, it states that (in page 46) by definition the process $S_t^{d/f}S_t^f$ is the foreign asset valued in the domestic currency and therefore should be driven under $\mathbb{P}^d $ by
$\frac{dS_t^{d/f}S_t^f}{S_t^{d/f}S_t^f} = r_ddt+\sigma_S.dW^d_t+\sigma_{d/f}.dW_t^d$

My question is:

1) What is the "$.$" in $\sigma_S.dW^d_t$ and $\sigma_{d/f}.dW_t^d$? I cannot find it in "Symbol Description" of the book.

If it is just multiplication, why there is no correlation in the the multi-dimension Ito's lemma? (theorem 2.2 in page 21) It say $dW^i_t.dW^j_t=\delta_i^jdt$

2) Why can we formulate the $S_t^{d/f}S_t^f$ like this? Is it an assumption?

Comment: It’s a dot product, and there is no correlation since it’s standard Brownian motion

Comment: Answering the second question, that is simply "the foreign asset valued in domestic currency" in formula.